# Render XML in table using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Please help me to render below XML data in the form of table using AngularJS

```
<EmployeeDetail>
    <employeeID>1564654</employeeID>
    <employeeName>Vinit</employeeName>
    <emailID>xyz@email.com</emailID>
  </EmployeeDetail>
  <EmployeeDetail>
    <employeeID>14654</employeeID>
    <employeeName>Varun</employeeName>
    <emailID>xyz@email.com</emailID>
  </EmployeeDetail>
```

Help me in this case as soon as possible

Comment: can you please tell me are you using $http module for fetch this data?

Comment: http://www.amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/working-xml-angular-js

Comment: Yes @Ahmer I m using $http like in JSON my code for JSON is   <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('myDB.json')
                .then(function (response) { $scope.details = response.data; });

                $scope.removerequest = function (row) {
                    $scope.details.splice($scope.delete.indexOf(row), 1);
                }
            });

        </script> but when I tried with XML it is not working so Please help me in this case

Comment: great just let me post the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('someUrlforXml').then(function(response) {
 $scope.EmployeeDetail = [];

/*setting up the response*/
var data = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
$scope.EmployeeDetail = data.EmployeeDetail;
```

if it is not work for you try [this link](http://rabidgadfly.com/2013/02/angular-and-xml-no-problem/)

Comment: visit this is link which one i mention in answer